# how to skip metabase synonym in oracle?

Tags: synonym, metabase

I'm trying to create a report in Metabase after connecting to an Oracle database, but I'm encountering errors because the DBA has set up synonyms by default. Do you happen to know how to configure synonym settings? I've read online that it can be found in the advanced options in the database, but I'm using the free version and I don't see that menu. I would appreciate any advice from someone who knows.

"When I tried using the Field Filter as a variable type, I encountered an ora-00905 error, and upon examining the executed SQL, it seems that the table owner is omitted during Oracle configuration. However, when I try to include the owner, it still results in an error.

Comment: Plase share what you've tried (example code) and what the result is.  Please explain what it means that the DBA has set up synonyms by default.  Is there a reason you cannot speak with that DBA for guidance?

Comment: ex) select * from tctpcot where 1 = 1 and {{stDt}} => 
"When executed like this, the actual executed SQL is forcibly prefixed with 'HDS_HIS.' before the table name. It seems to be caused by using variables with the 'Field Filter' type."  ==>log "select * from tctpcot where 1 = 1 and trunc("HDS_HIS"."tctpcot"."stDt") ORA=00904

Comment: Please update your question with this information. Since comments lack any sort of formatting, it's hard to see what you're trying to say here.  As indicated before, please clarify the question.  The information is is a start.